# How to add spaces to for loop output in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add one space in between each outcome in this for loop,

```
for (var i = -52; i <= 1066; i++) {
   document.write(i)
}
```

Comment: `document.write(i + ' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `&nbsp;` to do it

```js
for (var i = -52; i <= 1066; i++) {
       document.write(i+"&nbsp;");
}
```

Or just add to space in the `write`

```js
for (var i = -52; i <= 1066; i++) {
       document.write(i+" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help you out.

```
for (var i = -52; i <= 1066; i++) {
  document.write(' ' + i)
}
```

or

```
for (var i = -52; i <= 1066; i++) {
  document.write('&nbsp;' + i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 52; i <= 1066; i++) {
            document.write(i+'\t') }
```

Comment: I believe, the question is for a space, not a line break.

Comment: Edited the code. Wanted to add a tab space

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are designed to ignore whitespace such as spaces, typing in multiple ' ' (spaces) will be reduced to a single space. If you're looking to add multiple spaces in Javascript the easiest way is to use `&nbsp`. Such tags are called entities and numerous characters can be printed using entities. More can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

```
for(var i = 0;i < n;i++)
{
  document.write("&nbsp")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let result = [];
for (let i = -52; i <= 1066; i++) {
  result.push(i);
}
document.write(result.join(" "));
```

Suggestion: avoid using `document.write` at best, especially in a big for loop.

Comment: One more thing, if the variable `i` is only used in for loop, using `let` instead of `var` is better.

Comment: When I use console.log it does not write anything into web page?

Comment: Of course not, it logs everything in console, you can press `Ctrl + Shift + J `(Windows / Linux) or `Cmd + Opt + J` (Mac) to see the outputs.

Comment: Figured that out while playing around bad question...